# display the results c++ program

Tags: c++11

I need help with setw(). I have this fumction :

```
void PrintRecord(PLAYER &m, ostream &cout)
{

     cout << setw(3) << m.PlayerID << '\t' << m.LastName << ',' << setw(4)
        << m.FirstName;
    if ( m.Hits > 0 || m.Walks > 0 || m.Outs > 0 )
    {
        cout << "\t\t" << setprecision(3) << fixed << m.Hits << '\t'
            << m.Walks << '\t' << m.Outs << '\t' << m.BattingAvg
            << '\t' << m.OnBaseAvg << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

which is not printing my data in columns.

i want to print my data on alighn colmns,

thanks

Comment: Look at printf from cstdio. It lets you format your output.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the same width for each value in a column by calling `setw` before each value to be printed.  Usually you won't need to use '\t' when using `setw`.  Unlike `setprecision`, `setw` is not "sticky" so you need to set it before each printed value.

```
cout << setw(3) << m.PlayerID << setw(20) << m.LastName << ',' << setw(20)
    << m.FirstName;
if ( m.Hits > 0 || m.Walks > 0 || m.Outs > 0 )
{
    cout << setw(20) << setprecision(3) << fixed << m.Hits << setw(20)
        << m.Walks << setw(20) << m.Outs << setw(20) << m.BattingAvg
        << setw(20) << m.OnBaseAvg << endl;
}
```